# Display distinct groups in a database and for each one count number of distinct users

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am facing with this issue. You have a database let's say musicbands, containing an auto increment id column, band_name as var char, genre as var char, join_date as DateTime in format for example 2016-09-01 10:37:06.

What I want to do is to display number of distinct genres in my database, and for each one display unique number of bands and next to it the timestamp of last joined band of that genre.

I want to user Oracle SQL
Did a lot of queries but no luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, figure out which RDBMS you're going to use.

Comment: I am going to use Oracle Sql

Comment: I'm with @Strawberry. Please [edit] your question to delete the tags for the databases you're not using.

Comment: Have you looked at the `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` features available in all varieties of SQL? http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL 101

```
select 
genre, 
count(distinct band_name) as total_band_names, 
max(join_date) as max_join_date
from musicbands
group by genre
order by genre
```

formatting a date in a certain format is however a bit different depending on what RDBMS you use.

But for the Oracle RDBMS you can use TO_CHAR for it.

```
to_char(max(join_date), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as max_join_date
```

Comment: Thank you very much LukStorms. Sql is not among my strong points!! It solved the problem.